# Question at the end of the chapter on Functions in Halmos's naive set theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, relations

(i) $Y^\emptyset$ has exactly one element, namely $\emptyset$, whether $Y$ is empty or not, and (ii) if $X$ is not empty, then $\emptyset^X$ is empty.

How do you prove these statements to be true?

Comment: $X^Y$ is the set of functions with domain $Y$ and taking values in $X$. You should be able to prove these two statements now that you have the definition. It makes no sense to ask for help before you think about the problems.

Comment: That notation stands for the set of functions with domain equal $Y$ and range a subset of $X$.